# how to change content without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Following Code is what I tried to execute to to change the content without refreshing the page. I'm unable to execute the home.html and other pages into the main page while I'm trying to call. Can anyone help me out, I'm a beginner in this. Thanks in Advance !

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#content').load('home.html');
})
```

```css
ul #nav {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul #nav li {
  display:inlne;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  
  <head>
  <title>Website Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <!-- Nav -->
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Content which would change without refreshing the page  -->
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="simple.js">
    </script>
    
  </body>
  
</html>

<!-- home.html-->

<h1>Home</h1>
<p>Simple Text</p> 

<!-- about.html-->

<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>Simple Text</p> 

<!-- contact.html-->

<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>Simple Text</p>
```

Comment: and the home.html is in the same folder as your index?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#content').load('home.html');
})
```

is the the content of simple.js then change the hrefs to actual URLS like home.html and make your code look something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#nav").on("click","a",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link
    $("#content").load(this.href); // load the href
  });
})
```